# Unable to run test on RIDE --monitorcolors option not recognised

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I have been trying to run tests on RIDE (Robot Framework IDE). It used to warn about --monitorcolors option being depricated. In the latest install, it is unable to recognise. How do I change the options to make my tests run?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--monitorcolors` option has been replaced with `--consolecolors` in Robot Framework version 2.9. The usage documentation for `--consolecolors` is [here](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/2.9.2/_modules/robot/run.html). You must be using the old option somewhere - check the Arguments string in the Run tab in RIDE.