# Change robotframework RIDE argument files

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I recently upgraded my Python and Robot Framework to the same version via pip because I found out there were new keywords I needed on the selenium library

I am now on Robot Framework 3.0 (Python 2.7.9)

The error am getting now is "option --monitorcolors not recognized"

I found this [Unable to run test on RIDE --monitorcolors option not recognised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948948/unable-to-run-test-on-ride-monitorcolors-option-not-recognised) and I now understand that the reason is I need to edit the argument file to change from "monitorcolors" to "consolecolors"

RIDE always creates a new argument file every time I compile, so I want to change that so I can just hit the start button and it works.

I don't think there's anything wrong with my environment variables, but would that be a factor given all I did was upgrade my Robot Framework version and Selenium version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hélio's response in the user group:

That problem is fixed in RIDE 1.5.1.
Just upgrade RIDE, with:

`pip install -U robotframework-ride`

Comment: Do you have any references for that?
I'm using 1.5.2 and still facing the same problem....SO it's not related only to Ride's version....